# Consuming a WebService in Mule

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to add two flows. One to deploy a webservice and the other to consume it.
This is the code of the flows.

```
<flow name="servicesFlow2" doc:name="servicesFlow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="`localhost`" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[{message.inboundProperties['username'],message.inboundProperties['password']}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="authentifier" serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AuthenticationInterface" doc:name="SOAP" port="AuthenticationInterfaceSoapBinding"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://`localhost`:8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="servicesFlow1" doc:name="servicesFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="`localhost`" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AuthenticationInterface" doc:name="SOAP"/>
        <component class="com.logixy.platform.ws.Authenticate" doc:name="Java"/>
    </flow>
```

When running the application and trying to access the http endpoint, http://`localhost`:8081?username=test&password=test, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not call org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage.writeObject() : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action
---- Debugging information ----
-------------------------------
message             : Could not call org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage.writeObject()
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action
------------------------------- (com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException). Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:240)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:127)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:112)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:204)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:508)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.routeEvent(AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.java:84)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:75)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:64)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:271)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: Could not call org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage.writeObject() : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action
```

Any help please.

this is the method "authentifier" in the class Authenticate:

public String authentifier(String user1, String password1) {
        try {

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName,
                password);
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"
                        + user1 + "' and password='" + password1 + "'");
        if (res.next()) {
            return res.getInt("id") + "";

        }
        return "0";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "0";
}
```

plus this is the AuthenticationInterface:

public interface AuthenticationInterface {

```
public String authentifier(String user1, String password1);

public ArrayList<BL> liste_BL(int id_driver);

public ArrayList<String> liste_Client1();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with `#[{message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['username'],message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['password']}]` and one more thing .... why don't you change `<cxf:simple-service` to `<cxf:jaxws-service` ???

So you full flow would be somewhat like :-

```
<flow name="servicesFlow2" doc:name="servicesFlow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[{message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['username'],message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['password']}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="authentifier" serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AuthenticationInterface" doc:name="SOAP" port="AuthenticationInterfaceSoapBinding"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="servicesFlow1" doc:name="servicesFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AuthenticationInterface" doc:name="SOAP"/>
        <component class="com.logixy.platform.ws.Authenticate" doc:name="Java"/>
    </flow>
```

You can also use `<set-payload value="#[{header:INBOUND:username,header:INBOUND:password}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>` if the above doesn't works.....

Note:- Just check in your code you have a symbol **`**  in all you localhost here in the code...

Comment: thanks for your help, the error has changed and now i am getting this: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: Object[]

Comment: could able to post your Authenticate and AuthenticationInterface so that help you detect the error and run the same scenario here to test it ..

Comment: Have you implemented AuthenticationInterface in Authenticate class ? if yes it should have shown in your code.... And why are you returning 0 at the end of the method like return "0"; .. You could have returned any other String ..

Comment: yes i have implemented it in the Authenticate class but it not shown here.